# Plot command fails when followed by a readline()

Tags: plot, julia, readline

The following program produces a plot

```
using Plots
plot(cos)
```

but this one does not

```
using Plots
plot(cos)
readline()
```

I am using Julia 1.2.0 on macOS 10.11.6 with JupyterLab in Firefox 74.0. When encountering the `readline()` in the latter program it displays a text-entry box which accepts text input but there is never a plot made.

Answer (score 5):

Only the last output is displayed, try

```
using Plots
display(plot(cos)) 
readline()
```

Comment: I don't understand the emoji. You are using a shortcut. The full syntax is `p = plot(cos)`. Then just return `p` to the console whenever you want to see the plot. Your `readline` blocks the object returning from `plot` being returned.